# Disjoint Permutations Commute Proof Query

Tags: group-theory, permutations, proof-explanation

I came across a proof that disjoint permutations commute that I'll summarize here.

We want to prove $\alpha(\beta(i))=\beta(\alpha(i))$ (1)

If both permutations fix a point, namley $\alpha(i)=i$ and $\beta(i)=i$, this implies $\alpha(\beta(i))=i=\beta(\alpha(i))$. (2)

If $\alpha(i)=j\neq i$, this implies $\beta(i)=i$, by definition of disjoint permutations (3)

Also $\beta(j)=j$, "because otherwise, it wouldn’t be a bijection" (4)

Thus $\alpha(\beta(i))=\alpha(i)=j=\beta(j)=\beta(\alpha(i))$. (5)

Replace $\alpha$ with $beta$ in line 3-5 and the proof is complete (6).

I do not understand why line (4) has to be true. Why does being a bijection mean that $\beta$ has to fix $j$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not phrased that well.  If $\beta$ moved $j$, then $\alpha$ can't move $j$ by disjointness.  This says that $\alpha(j)=j$, but $\alpha(i)=j$.  Hence $\alpha$ is not a bijection-- a contradiction--so $\beta$ may not move $j$, meaning $\beta(j)=j$ as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

You indeed have $\beta(j)=j$.

**As $\alpha(i)=j \neq i$, you have $\alpha(j) \neq j$ as otherwise $\alpha$ won't be injective.** Therefore $\beta(j)=j$ as otherwise, $\alpha, \beta$ won't be disjoint.

*So, the key argument is $\alpha$ won't be a bijection. Not $\beta$ won't be a bijection.*

Comment: That makes much more sense. Thank you.